# What is the best approach to organize classes in models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have one app, is called "perms" - some custom permission system. Inside the model's file I have this class "Role".

```
# perms models.py
class Role(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    perms = models.ManyToManyField(Perm)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

#def ... some custom functions
```

Next, I have some apps in my project e.g. app1, app2, app2 etc. were I am using this Role class.  E.g.

```
# app1 models.py
from perms.models import Role 

class App1Role(Role): 
    # some custom fields
```

The question is if this is good approach or should I organize everything in a different way: to put all "AppXRole" classes in perms.models and then in appX.models import this particular AppXRole class?

What is the best way to manage this kind of app's dependencies in Django?

Comment: Implementing all the `AppRole` classes in `perms.models` module means, that every time you need to add another Role-dependent app, you have to change the `perms` application. This might be reasonable within your project, but sharing this application to another projects may cause some troubles. I don't post this as answer, because I don't know "the best way to do this", but I'd prefer your current approach.

Comment: Very strong argument for following first solution. For second approach I see only one advantage, that could be very helpful for developers to have all Role's of project in one place/one file... but this is breaking good patterns... thanks for your opinion @soon.

Comment: Your apps should be structured in such a way, that you can expand upon it's functionality (in other apps), while leaving the app itself intact. Imagine that you turn it into a package that you could install via pip - how would you do then? Not knowing the full details about your apps, from what I understand I agree with soon that your current approach is the best.